# Slot value not set in custom action

Tags: rasa

In my custom action, i had created a list of button with value take from database. After user click any of these button, slot ma_truong_hop is set with value from the button that user had clicked. After run action server, i check the log file and i clearly see that slot ma_truong_hop is set. But when i use tracker.get_slot(‘ma_truong_hop’) to get the value of slot ma_truong_hop, its value still none. any help would be greatly appreciated.

My custom action:

```
    statement = 'SELECT MA_CHI_TIET_TRUONG_HOP, TEN_CHI_TIET_TRUONG_HOP FROM CHATBOT_CHI_TIET_THU_TUC WHERE MA_CHI_TIET_THU_TUC = :ma_thu_tuc'
    
    ma_thu_tuc = tracker.get_slot('ma_thu_tuc')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(statement, ma_thu_tuc = ma_thu_tuc)
    res = cur.fetchall()

    button_list = []
    for ma_truong_hop, ten_truong_hop in res:
        title = ten_truong_hop
        payload = "/truong_hop{\"ma_truong_hop\": \"" + str(ma_truong_hop) + "\"} "
        button_list.append({ "title": title, "payload": payload })

    dispatcher.utter_message(text = "Thủ tục bạn tìm kiếm có các trường hợp sau: ", buttons = button_list)
    print(tracker.get_slot('ma_truong_hop'))
```

[Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSkNw.png)

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfGos.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are printing the result in the action that displays the buttons. The slot won't be set until the user actually clicks the button.